# Python script to extract lots of .rar

Tags: python, extract, rar

I have 95 folders filled with only .rar

I want to extract those folder with a little script :

```
import os
import rarfile

parent_directory = 'E:\Immo_JSON'
destination_directory = 'E:\OP'


for folder in os.listdir(parent_directory):
  
    folder_path = os.path.join(parent_directory, folder)
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        num_rar_files = 0
        with os.scandir(folder_path) as entries:
            for entry in entries:
                if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith('.rar') and rarfile.is_rarfile(entry):
                    num_rar_files += 1
        print(f"{num_rar_files}  .rar found in the folder {folder}")
```

I included a printf to show me if he found .rar inside those folder and it returns 0 for each folder.

There are only .rar inside those folders, not password protected and not corrupted since I can extract them manually.
Any ideas ?

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing with your current script?